# WAIT in Transaction - Firebird

Tags: indexing, firebird, transactions, wait

Can we set the index active when another transaction is in progress.
Will Firebird wait till the other transaction completes its operation and the index will become inactive/active (this is for reindexing) after that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Firebird will activate/deactivate indexes while there are other transactions using it.